# Floating point calculation error in Java

Tags: java

Help, I got a problem when adding double value with negative number

A sample program to show the problem:

```
    double newX = 850.0;
    double delta = -1.6994427191177073E12;
    double total = delta + newX;
    System.out.println("newX:" + newX);
    System.out.println("delta:" + delta);
    System.out.println("total:" + total);
```

but the given output is:

```
 newX:850.0
 delta:-1.6994427191177073E12
 total:-1.6994427182677073E12
```

I would expect the total value to be around "848.30055729". How to handle this calculation?

Regards,

Dennis

Comment: Do you know what the `E` means, towards the end of that big number?

Answer (score 4):

The computation is correct.

Lets start by converting your number from scientific notation

```
-1.6994427191177073E12
```

to decimal fixed-point notation:

```
-1699442719117.7073
```

This is because `E12` means that the number to the left of `E` is multiplied by 10<sup>12</sup>.

Once you perform the addition of that number and `850.0`, you get the result

```
-1699442718267.7073
```

Once you convert it to scientific notation by bringing the decimal point all the way to the left, you get the result printed by your program.

Comment: Oh sorry I do not realize that "E" means exponent, thank you! :)

Comment: The Tutorial explained that for in  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html, as you might recall from your study of the Tutorial, and the Java Language Specification (JLS) covers it in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2. Read the Fine Manual.